# multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want "runnable" to run at 5tps. This is not executing paralelly.

```
package tt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class mySpawner {

public int tillDone = 0;
public int tillMax = 0;
public ArrayList arrayList;
private myWorker myworking;
private ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(50);

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(System.nanoTime());
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mySpawner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
};


public void activate() {
    try {
        service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(50);
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void deactivate() {
    service.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: Not that it'll fix the problem, but you're initializing `service` twice in your code

Comment: problem is that it prints nanotime every 7 secs only. Shouldn it be printing every 200ms ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update:** Howard is right, my first example was wrong.

I verified this works if you change your `active()` method:

```
service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(50);
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        long nextTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            service.submit(runnable);
            long waitTime = nextTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, waitTime));
            nextTime += 200;
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: thanx whitefang. this will run @ 5 tps ryt?

Comment: This is doing something completely different. It starts 50 threads each running every 200 milliseconds. Thus after 200ms it will execute the first one and additionally the second one. After 400ms it will run three at the same time, and so on. It just doesn't show up, because each one takes 7 seconds and the thread isn't respawned before the action ends.

Comment: @Howard: thanks, I updated with a better answer that I verified holds at 5 per second for a long period.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:

- Your tasks are sleeping for 7 seconds during their execution
- You are scheduling a new task every 200ms
- You only have 50 threads in your executor

It should be clear, I hope, that you'll run out of pooled threads in just a few seconds, and you'll lose your parallelism.  You need to balance this better, either by reducing the rate or reducing the sleep.  Increasing the pool size won't help, you'll still run out of threads.

Comment: I put sleep there to emulate a task that runs for 7 secs. Right now its not running parallely thats d issue ( it prints nanotime and after 7 secs it prints next nanotime my doubbt is wont they print every 200 ms ?)

Comment: @user5574348 - pay attention to what @skaffman actually said ... and do some arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

`scheduleAtFixedRate` does only spawn a single thread but executes the runnable provided with a fixed rate.

- The action runs in less amount of time than the given period: in this case it is respawned with exactly the specified period.
- The action runs longer (your case): the action is started again immediately.

If you want to have the desired behaviour you may use the following pattern: Just execute the runnable once:

```
service.schedule(runnable, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but inside the runnable's `run` method add the next invokation by

```
service.schedule(runnable, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Nevertheless consider the arithmetic as described in the answer by skaffman.